# Can I use 100 Mbps Network Switch for Hadoop mini cluster setup?

Tags: networking, hadoop

I am willing to run a 12 Node Hadoop Cluster using virtual box. I have 3 real machine each running 4 datanodes nodes inside virtual box. I am able to connect 2 machine using a LAN wire and able to make a 8 node cluster. Now I have to connect the third machine via switch so that I will be able to run a 12 node cluster. RAM of my NameNode is 1 GB and all datanodes are 512MB. I am using 64 bit core i3 processor on all machines and each node has a capacity of 8GB. My question is can I use the following mentioned switch for my network topology?

http://www.flipkart.com/d-link-5-port-10-100base-t-unmanaged-switch-network/p/itmdffymrfgngzsf?pid=NSWDFFYGUQ9GHMF9&ref=1938618c-3737-471e-941b-3e4bb41972fe&srno=t_1&otracker=from-search&query=switch

As it supports 100 Mbps speed. My budget is limited as its a college project for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be slow, but will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is clearly not suited for typical Hadoop workloads. They require fast networks and lot of RAM. I had bet you will achieve better performances putting all your disks and RAM into one machine than with your mini cluster.

However, if it is for an educational only project, and nor plan to work on medium or large data  nor care about performance it will work. According to your setup I'm not sure if a 100mbs network will be the bottleneck.